# Reset custom taxonomy meta data after saving

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I added a new taxonomy for the Post and added some elements [Checkbox, Select, ColorPicker] and everything working great BUT when click on [Add New {taxonomy}] button the new taxonomy added by AJAX without reloading page so the settings of new elements don't change but built-in texts like [Name, Slug, Description] reset but not [Parent] select box.

How to reset the new custom meta fields??

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check would be to make sure you have no spaces or invalid characters in your custom taxonomy names... This would cause them not to save properly.

-shel

Comment: No problem with saving bra, After saving i need to reset checkbox, select colorpicker to their initial values